# Weird Issue when building with Android Studio! APK is sometimes 2MB smaller and is then not installable

Tags: android-studio, build, apk

I have this weird issue that when I build multiple times that sometimes the APK is 2MB smaller than it is normally.

The build has no errors but when I try to install it, it does not work. Its a debug apk.

I need to Clean the Project and then restart Studio to make a new build!

Is there a way to get around this bug or am I doing something wrong?